# how to get the list and detail views on the same one page website template

Tags: django

I'm trying to achieve this.
1. one page website with a list and detail view on the same template.
when the website loads, I have the thumbnails with all the list of items, I show that using a for loop and listview.

under that i have the same thing(items from the model) but in a form of carousel.( i can see all the items from the model in the slider with complete details)
these work fine.

but I want a detailed view in the same carousel slider. for eg: the user can see the list of items (thumbnail) and when clicked on a item , that  particular item should be active in the slider,
1. I cant get the list and detail view to work on the same template.
2.i cant get the detailed view to work in the same carousel slider.

MODELS.PY

```
class Cheese(models.Model):
TYPES_CHOICES=(
    ('COW', 'COW'),
    ('GOAT', 'GOAT'),
    ('SHEEP', 'SHEEP'),
    ('BUFFALO', 'BUFFALO'),
    ('COW, GOAT & SHEEP',  'COW, GOAT & SHEEP'),
    ('COW & SHEEP',  'COW & SHEEP')
    )

COUNTRY_CHOICES=(
    ('USA', 'USA'),
    ('UK','UK'),
    ('ITALY', 'ITALY'),
    ('FRANCE', 'FRANCE'),
    ('NETHERLANDS', 'NETHERLANDS')
)


origin = models.CharField(max_length=100)
title =  models.CharField(max_length=100)
types =  models.CharField(max_length=100, choices=TYPES_CHOICES)
about =  models.TextField()
serve =  models.CharField(max_length=1000)
image = models.ImageField(
    null=True,
    blank=True,
    width_field="width_field",
    height_field= "height_field")
width_field = models.IntegerField(default=550)
height_field = models.IntegerField(default=550)
country = models.CharField(max_length=50, choices=COUNTRY_CHOICES)
timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, auto_now=False)


def __unicode__(self):
    return self.title
```

VIEWS.PY

```
class HomeView(generic.ListView):
template_name= 'cheese/home.html'
model = Cheese
def get(self, request):
    queryset_list = Cheese.objects.all()
    queryset_wine = Wine.objects.all()
    form = FeedbackForm()

    #basic search query
    query = request.GET.get("q")
    if query:
        queryset_list = queryset_list.filter(
            Q(title__icontains=query)|
            Q(origin__icontains=query)|
            Q(types__icontains=query)|
            Q(about__icontains=query)
        ).distinct()

    context={
        'cheese': queryset_list,
        'form': form,
        'wine': queryset_wine,

    }  

    return render(request, self.template_name, context)
```

URLS.PY

```
urlpatterns = [
url(r'^$', views.HomeView.as_view(), name='home'),
url(r'^(?P<pk>[0-9]+)$', views.HomeView.as_view(), name='cheesedetail'),
```

]

Comment: best approach is AJax, you have the list, and when the user clicks, you send a request your backend with the Id of the object clicked, and return either as JSON or through context, and just refresh that part of page that has detailed object

Comment: thanks .. can u help me with some guides maybe a documentation or tutorials?

Comment: edit you question with the html part containing all the carousel codes, I will post an answer with the way to accomplish it

Comment: im trying so hard but i cant get it post ,, it asks me to check my indentation , i tried copy paste and also writing it myself .. didnt work.,, i have put it here,, can u pls check https://pastebin.com/GHEjPjaz

Answer (score 1):

You are using here CBV for the `HomeView` in a horrible way that I did not almost notice that you ae using CBV. Do not ever override `render` in get method. I see you are overidding it because of appending some items to context. **Then append items to context and do not override the render!**

```
class HomeView(ListView):
    template_name = 'cheese/home.html'
    query = Cheese.objects.all()

    def get_queryset(self):
        queryset = super().get_queryset()
        search_query = self.request.GET.get("q")
        return queryset.filter(
            Q(title__icontains=search_query)|
            Q(origin__icontains=search_query)|
            Q(types__icontains=search_query)|
            Q(about__icontains=search_query)
        ).distinct()

    def get_context(self):
        context = super().get_context() # gets context from parent method0
        context['form'] = FeedbackForm()
        context['wines'] = Wine.objects.all()
        return context
```

The main concept of using CBV's is that it tends to be more organised and it's based in inheritance.

You should consider using async javascript API calls (e. g. `AJAX`) in your templates. You can load/send your content dynamically to the server. Then you should create two separate views - ListView for Cheese with the list of cheese and then another DetailView with search form and getting data based on it. In the template you would define something like `window.onload = fetchDetailView()` and then the sender methods and you are done.

Comment: thanks .. i understood so i need to use AJAX, can u guide me to some tutorials or documentation to complate this task???

Comment: maybe you should read https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2016/08/29/how-to-work-with-ajax-request-with-django.html